# Delete a section in microsoft word - docx4j

Tags: ms-word, docx4j

Is there a way to delete a section and its contents programmatically using docx4j?

My requirement is to have a document template with 4 sections relating to product information about products A, B, C and D. The product information for each of them will have a combination of static text and dynamic data that will be generated at runtime and the dynamic info resides in the database tables. I am planning to include content controls under each product section for the dynamic data and once I get the data from the tables in the mid-tier, docx4j code will populate the content controls with the appropriate data.

If the user thinks he only needs to see A, B and D in the resulting document, my code should be able to not show any content from section C from the template and its static text and generate the final document with A, B and D sections.

Any ideas how to create such a template and appropriately delete sections? is there a way to do this?

Comment: I believe the approach to this is to locate the two section break objects which 'top and tail' the required section, and then remove the intermediate content -- I don't think there's a concept of a 'section' in the object model, hence why you need an approach like this. (FYI the underlying code needs to look for `SectPr` objects, perhaps using the `TraversalUtil` class).

Comment: okay good idea. but there will be multiple sections and hence section breaks. Any ideas about how I should differentiate between the sections that I will need and that I wont?

Comment: Well there are `id` and `display` attributes which can be applied to sections, but I reckon you'd have to experiment with a Word document / its XML to figure out what approach is going to work for you... Off the top of my head, it sounds like you need to hide sections in a generated document, based on user selection. If that _is_ the case, then the `display` attribute sounds like the one you need (possible values are `true / none / condition`).